# Vauxhall/Opel/GM Vivaro 'Alarm Pre-installation Kit'?

Tags: electrical, vauxhall, alarm, van

My mate, upon having just obtained a Vivaro 1.6 CDTI, read something in the manual and I'm curious as to what the 'Alarm Pre-Installation Kit' is. I've never heard of anything like this, and looking on the Vauxhall websites, there's no information on it at all. (Bearing in mind, I'm in the UK, so not much info on anything to begin with...)

Does this mean the van IS fitted with an alarm? Or is it a case of it being set up and ready to get a plug-and-play system that'll fit? Or is it going to need a full alarm fit regardless? At a loss as to what it means, so anyone who could shed some light onto this one, please do! Preferably if you've had experience with this, though just any information will do! TIA!

Comment: I don't know, but I would interpret that to mean that something was installed to make adding an alarm easier later on.  Like a special wiring harness, etc.

Comment: I tend to agree with @JPhi1618. It might be worth a call to the dealership or manufacturer to ask for clarification.